# How to tee multiple times to a single file and program

Tags: java, bash, parallel-processing, pipe, tee

**Background**

I am having following command stored as a shell script in `execution.sh`

`cat input_file | tee output_file | java program`

I used `./execution.sh &` successfully to read from input_file, store the data in single output_file and also send as input to java program.

**Problem**

I want to output data from `input_file` multiple times to `output_file` and also to java program.

e.g. Reading same `input_file` say 5 times in parallel and send the data to a single `output_file` and single `java program`.

**Edit**

**Tried solution**

```
execution.sh

{
 python2 readLines.py &
 python2 readLines.py &
 python2 readLines.py &
 python2 readLines.py &
 python2 readLines.py &
} | tee  output_file | java program 

readLines.py

with open('inputfile') as f:
    for line in f:
       print line
```

I am using this currently, please comment if any issues anybody sees such as race condition etc here.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Because I don't think it's a *good idea*.

Comment: It's a terrible idea as without an exclusive write lock each process will overwrite data from the others.  Plus it's very difficult to manage the data ordering even if you do have an exclusive lock.  Why do you want to do this is a very good question.

Comment: I want to simulate something that apache does. Multiple processes are writing logs to a single `error_log` file which are also being `tee`ed to a consumer written in java. I do not care about the order of the logs what matters to me is total number at the end that is processed by java program.

Comment: Apache does not do anything like the process you have described.

Comment: I could see multiple `httpd` processes running on a host which is running apache server. There is only one file which receives all error logs in my case  configured as `/var/log/httpd/error_log`. Please correct my understanding in case if is flawed.

Comment: Make a small program that reads a line from the the input, write it and sleep for a small random time. Start this program 5 times with output redirected to the outputfile.

Comment: I think you should add a very explicit example to your question.  It is not completely clear what you are looking for.

Comment: @Walter A : did something similar you had suggested. @ Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen : have a look at a solution I am trying to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Reading same input_file say 5 times in parallel and send the data to a single output_file and single java program

Let's just ignore the »*parallel*« part. Writes should only be made **sequentially**.

```
( for i in {1..5}; do cat input_file; done ) | tee out_file | java program
```

or in short

```
cat input_file{,,,,} | tee out_file | java program
```

Both commands print the file 5 times in a row.

If you really want to write in **parallel**, you could start the `cat` commands as background jobs:

```
( for i in {1..5}; do cat input_file & done ) | tee out_file | java program
```

This method guarantess that `output_file` contained all bytes from `input_file` exactly five times, but (of course) interleaved. There is a high chance that not only the lines, but also the bytes will end up interleaved. What does that mean?

If you have the file

```
abc
xyz
```

and print it two times in parallel, the output might become

```
ababcc

xxyz
yz
```

If that doesn't bother you, also keep in mind that that there are sequences of bytes which lose/change their meaning if they aren't appearing in that sequence, for instance windows new lines `\r\n` or multibyte unicode characters.

Comment: Edited my question to illustrate what I am trying. Please comment.